# Generate Unique Random Matlab Numbers with a range

Tags: matlab, random

Say I want 5 numbers between 1 to 10. However, I do not want any number to be repeated. How do I do this?

I thought of doing

```
 randi([1,length(a)])
```

Or this :

```
 (10-1).*rand(5,1) + 1
```

But then, this only gives me one number at a time! I want unique numbers and this will nto guarantee it.

Comment: Please try something.

Comment: K. Well, that's what I've done till now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is by using `randperm`:

```
N = 10;    % Numbers from 1 to N will be permuted
n = 5;    % Numbers to be extracted
x = randperm(N);    % Permute numbers between 1 and N
x = x(1:n);    % Retain first n
```

This can be generalized to any set of values:

```
N = 10;    % Length of vector of N numbers to be permuted
y = randn(N, 1);    % Vector from which you want to extract values
n = 5;    % Numbers to be extracted
x = randperm(N);    % Permute numbers between 1 and N
x = y(x(1:n));    % Retain first n of y
```

The problem is when N is large and n is small:

```
tic
N = 1e7;
n = 2;
x = randperm(N);
x = x(1:n);
toc
```

Then you need to find a better solution. If you have the Statistics Toolbox, try:

```
tic
x = randsample(N, n, false);
toc
```

Another approach, which is also slow but doesn't make use of `randperm` or `randsample`:

```
N = 1e7;
n = 2;
y = randn(N, 1);
tic
x = randn(N, 1);
[x x] = sort(x);
x = y(x(1:n));
toc
```

Comment: Well actually, why don't you just use:  x = randperm(10,5), a one-liner.

Comment: @roybatty You are right - on new Matlab versions you can do it in one line.